# How to print the plugin shortcode into wordpress administration page

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have a plugin to display the advertisement from external API. In this plugin I have used shortcode to display Advertisement. This functionality was working properly. But I need to display the shortcode in my wordpress admin page. Kindly suggest some solution. Thanks advance

Comment: Where do you want to display your shortcode in the admin side? which pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Where in the admin side either it is Page , Post or Widget you can add shortcode directly like **[my_shortcode]** and **replace "my_shortcode" with your shortcode string** .